# How do I use JTransforms to analyze and display the frequency spectrum of audio samples from ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, signal-processing

Currently, I'm using `JTransforms` to perform FFTs on audio samples I duplicated off the `MediaCodecAudioRenderer`, customized with a hook to duplicate the decoded buffer, from an ExoPlayer player using an RTMP `MediaSource`.

What I got is a 4096 (or a 4608... yeah, some MP3s strangely had non-power-of-2 sample sizes and I don't know why)-length `ByteBuffer`. That's what I have to put into the `FloatFFT_1D` or the `DoubleFFT_1D` object, correct?

Right now my code is as follows:

```
crf.setHook((dupe, format) -> {
        if(currentMediaSource == mMediaSourceAudio) {
            byte[] data = new byte[dupe.limit()];
            dupe.position(0);
            dupe.get(data);

            if(format != null) {
                new FFTTask(data, format).execute();
            }
            Log.i("straight_from_renderer", data.length+" "+format);
        }
    });
...
...
private class FFTTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, float[]> {
    byte[] bufferContents;
    MediaFormat format;
    FFTTask(byte[] samples, MediaFormat format) {
        this.bufferContents = samples;
        this.format = format;
    }
    float[] floatMe(short[] pcms) {
        float[] floaters = new float[pcms.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pcms.length; i++) {
            floaters[i] = pcms[i];
        }
        return floaters;
    }
    short[] shortMe(byte[] bytes) {
        short[] out = new short[bytes.length / 2]; // will drop last byte if odd number
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
            out[i] = bb.getShort();
        }
        return out;
    }
    float[] directFloatMe(byte[] bytes) {
        float[] out = new float[bytes.length / 2]; // will drop last byte if odd number
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
            out[i] = bb.getFloat();
        }
        return out;
    }
    private double db2(double r, double i, double maxSquared) {
        return 5.0 * Math.log10((r * r + i * i) / maxSquared);
    }
    double[] convertToDb(double[] data, double maxSquared) {
        data[0] = db2(data[0], 0.0, maxSquared);
        int j = 1;
        for (int i=1; i < data.length - 1; i+=2, j++) {
            data[j] = db2(data[i], data[i+1], maxSquared);
        }
        data[j] = data[0];
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected float[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //WARNING: bufferContents is from a 2-channel 48k bitrate audio, so convert to mono first?
        /*
        byte[] oneChannel = new byte[bufferContents.length/2];
        for(int i = 0; i < oneChannel.length; i+=2) {
            oneChannel[i] = bufferContents[i*2+2];
            oneChannel[i+1] = bufferContents[i*2+3];
        }
        */
        float[] dataAsFloats = floatMe(shortMe(bufferContents));
        int fftLen = dataAsFloats.length/2;
        fft = new FloatFFT_1D(fftLen);
        fft.complexForward(dataAsFloats);
        String log = "";
        float[] magnitudes = new float[dataAsFloats.length/2];
        float magMax = 0;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        float dominantFreq = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < dataAsFloats.length/2; i++) {
            float re = dataAsFloats[2*i];
            float im = dataAsFloats[2*i+1];
            magnitudes[i] = (float)(Math.sqrt(re * re + im * im) / 1e7);
            //log += re+" "+im+" "+magnitudes[i]+"\n";
            if(magnitudes[i] > magMax) {
                magMax = (float)(magnitudes[i]);
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        dominantFreq = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE) * maxIndex / fftLen;
        Log.i("fft_results", magMax+" "+dominantFreq);
        return magnitudes;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(float[] res) {
        super.onPostExecute(res);
        //fftListener.onFFTResultsAvailable(res);
        caView.feedFFTMagnitudes(res);
    }
}
```

I commented out the channel splitting code because I'm not sure whether to put that byte array in wholesale, or split it by channel then put the data from one of the channels in.

But then the final `res` values are really noisy - as in, the magnitudes are chaotic and display no obvious pattern as it should be from the usual audio analysis images - instead, it's just a tight zigzag, with high values from frequencies above 20000 Hz.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong was the bytes-to-short conversion, turns out. Now I just use this function to convert two bytes to a short:

```
private short getSixteenBitSample(byte high, byte low) {
    return (short)((high << 8) | (low & 0xff));
}
```

Then cast the short to a float in the conversion array. THEN put that conversion array through the FFT.

Comment: I am  trying to build audio visualizer with exoplayer. Can you provide me your full implementation of raw audio bytes -> fft conversion part.